# Find x value in function if I know returned value

Tags: javascript, math

I have javascript function like this:

```
   function(x) { 
       return x + 2; 
   };
```

How can I find the value of x when returned value is for example 10 ? 
I need to find formula so I can apply it on other different functions.

Comment: `x + 2 = 10` -> `x = 10 - 2`. Next is your turn to make this into code

Comment: I am looking for general solution, formula, so I can apply this to many different functons

Answer (score 1):

You are asking to define the inverse of a function. In general a solution to this does not exist. Suppose your function was

```
function(x) {
    return x*x;
};
```

When you ask for the value of `x` that returns `9`, do you want `3` or `-3`? In general, you cannot do this if your function is not one-to-one (injective). But even if your function *is* one-to-one, you can't really make a general rule for what the inverse would be. You'd just have to do it on a case-by-case basis.